# AngularJS ngRoutes not always working on mobile browsers

Tags: angularjs, mobile, click, ngroute

I am building my website based on MEAN stack and I am having trouble with angular routing on mobile browsers for which I am using client side routing with ngRoute.

The site works fine in every possible desktop browser, even the mobile design (it has a different menu than the desktop version), but on mobile browsers I have to click about 10 times before the menu responds in both versions (desktop and mobile - depends on the resolution of the browser), that goes for every link inside the website. I have tried googling but have not found anyone with similar issues.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where do I start troubleshooting this? I am using ngAnimate for ng-view animations and some css transitions for the menu borders.

The development version of the website can be found here: http://meanapp1-boilerplatesand.rhcloud.com

Excuse the foreign language, the content isn't the issue here anyway.

Routes code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'angular-carousel',
  'ngTouch',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngResource',    
  'myApp.domov',
  'myApp.onas',
  'myApp.fotogalerija',
  'myApp.fotogalerija.single',
  'myApp.novice',
  'myApp.novice.single',    
  'myApp.kontakt',
  'myApp.storitve',
  'myApp.version',
  'myApp.admin',
  'myApp.meni',
  'duScroll'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/domov'});
}]);
```

And then for every module declared I have more or less the same code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.novice', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'myApp.novice.single'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/novice', {
templateUrl: 'novice/novice.html',
controller: 'noviceCtrl'
});
}])
```

I have declared modules that aren't acessible from the main menu as submodules of menu item modules. The routing code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.fotogalerija.single', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource',     'angular-carousel'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/fotogalerija/:item/single', {
    templateUrl: 'fotogalerija/single/single.html',
    controller: 'singleCtrl'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/fotogalerija/:item/single/:index', {
    templateUrl: 'fotogalerija/single/single.html',
    controller: 'singleCtrl'
  });
}])
```

Comment: you need to post code please....show us your routes config

Comment: I checked on my browser FF, and menu item click looks fine to me.

Comment: I've tried on two different android phones in firefox and chrome, it's not working for me. I've added the code.

Comment: getting script error on chrome here

Comment: There was a random 'new' before a function declaration, I removed it and the error is now gone, the problem remains though..